# Database vs fstream access

Tags: mysql, database, performance, sqlite, fstream

I have a (local) database (MySQL 5.1 at Ubuntu 10.10) with some 15000 tables each with ~1 000 000 rows on average. Each table has 6 DOUBLE columns. The storage engine is MyISAM. I have a C++ application that loads the data one table at a time and performs some calculations.
The way I retrieve the data from the database is simply by: SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp; (timestamp is the first column (DOUBLE) marked as UNIQUE)
By far most of the time is spent in loading and fetching. It takes ~15s to load and fetch all the rows in one table (tried with the native C API, C++ Connector and MySQL Query Browser).
When I load the same dataset from disk (plain text file) using fstream the same operation takes only ~4s.

Is it possible for MySQL or any other database (SQLite?) to get anywhere near this value?
Although, I have mostly simple SELECTS and INSERTS (+ one simple JOIN) I like the idea of database because it is somewhat easier to manage large data sets, so I would stick with it even at cost of some performance loss, but 15/4s per table is way too much given the number of tables. I would be fine with 6/4s though...

Thanks.
Petr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequential scan of all records isn't exactly the most convincing use case for a relational database, but I definitely would encourage you to benchmark SQLite as well.  It's generally considered to be a high performance replacement for custom file I/O.

Comment: Thanks. So far looking very good SQLite is marginally slower ~1s per table than the filesystem, so very much what I wanted. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Reading a file is not the same as using SQL to fetch the data. Reading a file only involves reading from the disk and putting it into memory. Thats it.

Now, using SQL to fetch structured data, now thats different. First, MySQL has to parse the query and structure it so it can execute it and read the data. When executing the query, MySQL opens the database file and reads some meta data related to that database.

Then, when that is done, it parses the file and fetches the data according to the query. There is also a small overhead because the communication between client and server is done via. sockets.

So, there is a **huge** difference between file access and what MySQL does. With MySQL you get much, *much* more, at the cost of speed.

Why do you need 15 000 tables anyway? I sense a flaw in your design if you need so many tables...

Comment: Thanks for answers. The data I am processing come from a space probe with 40 detectors. The raw data are stored in files. One file == one day == 40 detectors. Each detector takes on average 15 records per second. I need to prepare data for analysis (compute pointing of the beams) this is done using software given to me. Then I need to store the intermediate results somewhere (database?). My C++ software loads the data from that place. I need to process one year of data => 365*40 = 14600...

Answer (score 0):

If performance is of absolute concern, you can also experiment with mmap. This allows you to have a disk-backed memory area, exploiting very well optimized virtual memory and caching code.

I've seen an application (used in a major social networking site) that, for a very specific need, replaced a cluster of 8 large MySQL servers with optimized C++ code running on a single blade at ~5-10% utilization. (It calculated the social graph and shortest paths between users).

In general, you end up paying for the generalized solution. Analyse your needs carefully, apply algorithmic knowledge, then choose your weapon.. 
Many designers make the mistake of choosing what they know, then trying to fudge algorithms into it, and finally taking care of the needs.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're absuing the database fairly badly by having 15,000 tables. This is not how these databases are intended to work.

Secondly, any client-server database is likely to need several copy operations in memory, which will impose an upper limit on the speed even when the data are already in memory. Something like sqlite may avoid (some of) these copies by using data directly from the buffer.

You're using a SQL database for something it's not intended for - and abusing it, at that. I wouldn't expect it to do a very good job.